# How to test ajax application using webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Is there some specific way to test ajax based web application using webdriver?

Comment: What troubles do you have? In general you must use a lot of waits

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should be careful when you write tests for pages that use JavaScript/Ajax heavily.
Main point in such case is to use wait condition each time you do something and result is not available instantly or via page change. When you need to add a wait condition examine behavior of the page and try to find some event that is a sign for you that operation is completed (attribute change, new element appears or disappears and so on).